# window close event is not firing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, firefox

I have Firefox browser (version 38.0.5)

I want to fire event in JavaScript when browser is closed as:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        window.alert("sadas");
    };
```

Its not working in Firefox, but works in IE.

I refered this from :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the example that MDN is showing: they are returning a string, and that is all. You aren't allowed to do whatever in `onbeforeunload`:

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.

In the case of Firefox, they expect you to return a string and Firefox shows that as a confirmation.

Comment: then how can i show alter and be confirm that event is getting fired?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the string you want the user to be prompted with and let the browser prompt the user with that string. The documentation you linked to says explicitly that calls to alert() may be ignored.

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.